# How make Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Function more reliable during high traffic issues?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I cannot understand, why I always receive `TimeoutException` in my Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Topology.

I have the following configuration for my Spring Cloud Stream Functions:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: foo

  cloud:
    function:
      definition: transformKey;mapData
    stream:
      bindings:
        transformKey-in-0:
          destination: incoming-topic
        transformKey-out-0:
          destination: repartitioned-topic
        mapData-in-0:
          destination: repartitioned-topic
        mapData-in-1:
          destination: joining-topic
        mapData-out-0:
          destination: converted-outcome-topic

      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            min-partition-count: 60
            auto-add-partitions: true
            required-acks: all
            producer-properties:
              retries: 2
            functions:
              transformKey:
                applicationId: transform-key-appid
              mapData:
                applicationId: mapdata-appid
          bindings:
            mapData-in-1:
              consumer:
                materializedAs: joining-store
            transformKey-out-0:
              producer:
                sync: true
```

My focus is currently the first iteration, where I just transform the key, so that the information become repartioned. The key is small (just a few bytes) and the value can have a bit more bytes: 1-4 KiB.

Unfortunatelly I get the following error:

```
Expiring 3 record(s) for repartitioned-topic-55:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
```

My expectation is, when producing information takes to long, the whole function would run slower. But this seems not the case. The the data consumption on `transformKey-in-0` is still processing althoug the batch cannot be cleared as fast. I can't imagine, that there is no reliable solution for this situation. Or maybe I have a misunderstanding in the process.

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this issue?

Comment: This error comes from `batch.size` producer config and isn't associated with high traffic, but rather low traffic when there's not enough data to send in a full network request

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer. Sorry for the late response. I did some tests. After I batch extremly, the Stream works reliable. After an elmination procedure, I figured out, that the broker couldn't process this amount of data, which results in long network responses. Scaling up solved the problem.

Comment: Feel free to to post your solution below as an answer